# I have a few questions about MPAndroidCharts

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

1. The data in my graphs use milliseconds and look approximately like this:

   [1534928499109,52],[1534928522758,49],[1534928546408,51],[1534928570036,47],[1534928593671,54],

   but with many thousand data points. For some reason the points stack on top of each other like in the picture I've attached. How can I fix this? This also happens with HelloCharts.
   [Points stacking on top of each other.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAC9c.jpg)
2. I prefer MPAndroidChart but HelloCharts got this awesome view, previewChart. Here's an example:  https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android. Does MPAndroidCharts support previewCharts or something similar?
3. I am currently using a valueformatter to change milliseconds to date. Can I somehow get the difference between the smallest and biggest currently visible value and this way dynamically change the valueformatter to format more specific time?
   Thanks in advance for any answers!

Answer (score 0):

Only answering 3.:

`chart.visibleXRange` gives you the difference between the lowest and the highest visible x value. Similarly, `chart.visibleYRange` gives the values for the Y axis.

Be aware that (if you have defined a dragOffsetX) when scrolled all the way to the left or the right border of the chart, then the lowest or the highest value, respectively, is the lowest/highest value actually occurring in your data, but not the x value corresponding to the left/right border of the chart. To get that value, you can use `chart.getValuesByTouchPoint(...)` and `chart.contentRect`.

I use the following function to determine the exact interval between labels which helps me decide in what granularity I want to format the labels (in my case seconds vs milliseconds). The main part which transforms the `rawInterval` into `interval` is taken from `com.github.mikephil.charting.renderer.AxisRenderer.computeAxisValue` and translated to Kotlin:

```
fun calculateIntervalBetweenLabels(): Double {
    val range = chart.getValuesByTouchPoint(chart.contentRect.right, 0f, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).x - chart.getValuesByTouchPoint(chart.contentRect.left, 0f, YAxis.AxisDependency.LEFT).x
    val rawInterval = range / chart.xAxis.labelCount
    var interval = Utils.roundToNextSignificant(rawInterval).toDouble()
    val intervalMagnitude = Utils.roundToNextSignificant(10.0.pow(log10(interval).toInt())).toDouble()
    val intervalSigDigit = (interval / intervalMagnitude).toInt()
    if (intervalSigDigit > 5) {
        interval = floor(10 * intervalMagnitude)
    }
    return interval
}
```

In simpler cases without dragOffsetX, the first line could be replaced by `val range = chart.visibleXRange`.

In my ValueFormatter I do this:

```
override fun getFormattedValue(value: Float): String {
    return when {
        calculateIntervalBetweenLabels().roundToLong() >= 1000 -> formatValueInSeconds(value)
        else -> formatValueInMilliseconds(value)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about visibleXRange. Super useful!

Answer (score 0):

I've figured a few things out. In case anyone comes across this in the future and wonders the same thing.

1. MPAndroidCharts class Entry uses Float. Max value for Float is 2^23 and everything above that is rounded, the points get the same x-value. I fix this by subtracting 1.5 billion from every value and dividing by 100. Then in the ValueFormatter, I undo this.
2. I don't know, yet.
3. My solution was to calculate the difference between every value that gets formatted in the ValueFormatter. If the difference is less than zero, the formatter has looped around and that value is the displayed interval. Another solution suggested using `chart.visibleXRange`, which is much simpler.

Comment: Oh, visibleXRange don't work if the method in answer 1. is used.